# Get a dict whose keys are combinations of a given dict without duplicate values

Tags: python

I have a dict like this:

```
dic = {'01':[1,2], '02':[1], '03':[2,3]}
```

what I want to achieve is a new dict, its keys are combinations of the keys (group in 2 only), and without duplicate values. 
in this simple example, the output will be:

```
newDic = {'0102':[1,2], '0103':[1,2,3],'0203':[1,2,3]}
```

thanks a bunch!!

Comment: We will help you with your code.. Where is it? Don't be shy, show it to us :)

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations` to get pairs of keys, then create new keys being concats of the pairs of existing keys you got and merge the lists.

Comment: Hint: `>>> list(itertools.combinations(dic.keys(), 2))`

Comment: @alKid agree, have removed my solution for a bit :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: hoho guys, this is not homework or something...there is no other code, i just want to get this asap for something i am working (in rumba script...sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get the different combo's of keys. and then use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to get unique values of the list. Put it all into a [dictionary-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) like this:

```
>>> dic = {'01':[1,2], '02':[1], '03':[2,3]}
>>> import itertools as IT
>>> {a+b: list(set(dic[a]+dic[b])) for a,b in IT.combinations(dic, 2)}
{'0203': [1, 2, 3], '0301': [1, 2, 3], '0201': [1, 2]}
```

You can also use [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) to have the keys the way you want them:

```
>>> {''.join(sorted([a,b])): list(set(dic[a]+dic[b])) for a,b in IT.combinations(dic, 2)}
{'0203': [1, 2, 3], '0103': [1, 2, 3], '0102': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newDic = { a+b : list(set(dic[a] + dic[b])) for a in dic for b in dic if b>a }
```